# Loading many buffered images 100+ to memory in java

Tags: java, out-of-memory, bufferedimage

I am writing a program that involves a custom search for many images. When the user enters their search criteria the corresponding images are retrieved either from the cache or the server.  I have a JTable which displays links to the corresponding images.  When the user clicks on a link the image is displayed on a JPanel.   I can read an image from the hard drive when a link is clicked but it is not as fast as I would like.  It takes a couple of seconds to  load it.  I have tried creating an array of BufferedImages but if the search returns many results i go oom.  I am wondering what would be the best way to make the images display more quickly when the link is clicked.

Heres how I obtain the images...

```
Public void getFile(String fileName){
File file = new File("./cache/"+fileName);
    boolean exists = file.exists();

    BufferedImage returnImage =null;
    if(exists){
        try {

            returnImage = ImageIO.read(file);
            System.out.println("Found In Cache!");
        } catch (IOException|IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            try {
                if(fileName != null){
                returnImage = downloadImage(fileName);
                System.out.println("Found ON Server :(");
                }
            } catch (IOException |IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }else{
        try {
            if(fileName != null){
            returnImage = downloadImage(fileName);
            System.out.println("Found ON Server :(");
            }
        } catch (IOException |IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return returnImage; 

}
}
```

and this is where I put them in an array...

```
BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[numOfSearchResults];

for(SearchResult r: results){
     images[i] = imageCache.getFile(r.imageName);
}
```

Basically I'm just wondering what would be the best way to preload the images without going oom.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: Loading an image from disk and showing it should not take a few seconds, unless it is a really big image (big in disk size). Have you profiled your application to see whether the image loading is indeed the bottleneck ?

Comment: @SteveKuo I edited to contain the correct tag.

Comment: @stevekuo oom = out of memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds unreasonable that loading an image from disk takes a couple of seconds, unless the images are *really, really BIG* (10 Megapixels or more). First determine where the time is really spent.

For caching, you could hold references to each image you loaded using java.lang.ref.SoftReference - this allows the image to be garbage collected *before* you run OOM.
If really unavoidable, I would use a multilayered caching system, first level with SoftReferences in memory, and for server based images an additional on-disk cache. When looking for an image, the in-memory cache is checked first, if nothing is found there the disk cache is checked and if still not found the image is loaded the usual way.

Comment: The images are pretty big 3300 x 2550 I tested it with smaller images and they read from disk pretty quick.  Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to load only part of an image ? At that size and at full resolution, it would not be possible to display all of it so might as well just load a tile as Photoshop probably does.

Comment: @JamesPoulson Well, TC did not say what image formats he is using, but for the usual suspects JPG, PNG etc, there isn't much you can do unless you write your own image decoder (and I doubt you could gain much). Photoshop btw. *does* load the entire image, too. The tiling approach is then used to enable swapping of parts of the image to disk while you work on it. It can't use this directly on a generic image file, say a PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Do not load all/too many images, load couple images before the current index and couple images after the current index.

Implement image loader as a different thread which does not block main execution thread and load additional images when user is watching current loaded image.

Comment: I'd probably take a look at the Executors API for this

Answer (score 0):

You can open an InputStream to all the images and close the ones the user hasn't clicked on and just use the one you need.

That way you don't have to buffer all the images but have them 'in reach' already when the user clicks.

But as @Robin has commented correctly, it really should not take long to load an average sized image.

I'm not sure if that gains you much in performance, but depending on your situation, it could.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the full sized image, I'd scale them down on load to decrease the amount of memory.  You have to remember that images load in memory are no longer compressed.

If you have control over the source images, I'd consider generating thumbnails to help them load quicker.  We use thumbnails of 200x200 & even over a SMB based share, they take less then a second to load